# java application distribution with extension api

Tags: java, distribution, executable-jar, software-packaging

I am planning to write some java application & planning to distribute in free & commercial versions.Basically my idea is to get some money from out of it from corporate users.
I would like provide extension API which other user can write some jar & include in the product.

Please help me with the following questions.

1) If I distribute as JAR anyone can see my code even if I do obfuscation.I think there are some paid de-obfuscators..making exe or JNI an option but it's not an effective solution.
Microsoft products don't have this problem. Any advice?

2)If I make open source, I won't get much gain because,business don't usually go for support until unless its huge product like IBM websphere or RAD.  Any inputs to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider a dual license scheme: release your source code under the GPL, and the companies that don't want to comply with the therms of the GPL would need to purchase a commercial license.

Comment: oh.ok.so the same product can be selled with different licenses..I dont have much idea about license..going through some stuff in online though!!!.  so what about the hiding the java source code? All these problems are with java not with microsoft products.